# angularJS array element shows as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, undefined

I am debugging a web app written in angularjs, I can see that the array contains all the values, but when I begin iterating through the items and want to see the value for each on my watch, it shows as undefined, but I can see the array and the values. It might be the way I am setting the counter?

This is what shows in developer tools in Chrome:

[image: debugging screen]

When I select data.[i].Name on item 0, it says that it is undefined, but as you can see on the right, the array contain values.

Can you see where is my error?

Thank you,
Erasmo

**updated screen shot**

[image: undefined key values]

Comment: You should loop over `data.data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `data` object you're iterating over actually contains another attribute called `data`, so you need to reference this as `data.data` at the start of your loop.

You also need to define the array item in your function callback, then you can reference it without the index `i`:

```
angular.forEach(data.data, function(item) {
    var b = {
        Name: item.Name,
        Email: item.Email
    };

    $scope.arr.push(b);
});
```

I'm leaving `i` out for brevity, and because it is not relevant to the operation of your loop. You can of course reintroduce it as you see fit.

By adding this parameter to your function callback, you are telling the iterator, "When I loop through this array called `data`, just call each entry `item`." This way you don't have to maintain a counter. For a more generic example, these two loops produce the same output:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

angular.forEach(['a', 'b', 'c'], function(item) {
    console.log(item);
}); 

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

You can still get a handle to the current index of your loop as well as the object itself from the function callback:

```
angular.forEach(data, function(item, index, obj) {
    console.log("Item " + index + " of " + obj + " is " + item);
});
```

For more information, see the [AngularJS API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach).

Comment: Let me give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: I can access the array now, just that now I see the keys: Name and Email as undefined. Please see my newest screen shot.

Comment: none of the options are working. i keep seeing the array with data, but when I attempt to assign the values to the b array, they show as undefined.

Comment: I am sorry @Bucket, I do not have a lot of experience. How can I show you how item looks?

Comment: @erasmocarlos Oh, I see why - your `data` object should actually be `data.data`. See your first screenshot.

Comment: @erasmocarlos See my edits. The `data` object returned by your Promise has yet another property called `data` which actually references the array you want. Reference this as `data.data`.

Comment: @erasmocarlos happy to help

Comment: I have another question, and I will add it shortly to this forum. I hope you are around and can spare sometime to see if you can offer a hand. I think is a simple question but for me is challenging.